# Chronicle Queue: How to read excepts/documents with different WireKey?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue, chronicle-wire

Assume a chronicle queue, and a producer that writes 2 types of messages into the queue.
Each type of message is written with a different "WireKey".

```java
// Writes: {key1: TestMessage}
appender.writeDocument(w -> w.write("key1").text("TestMessage"));

// Writes: {key2: AnotherTextMessage}
appender.writeDocument(w -> w.write("key2").text("AnotherTextMessage"));
```

**Question:**

How can I write a single-threaded consumer that can read both types of messages and handle them differently?

**What I've tried:**

```java
// This can read both types of messages, but cannot
// tell which type a message belongs to.
tailer.readDocument(wire -> {
    wire.read().text();
});
```

```java
// This only reads type "key1" messages, skips all "key2" messages.
tailer.readDocument(wire -> {
    wire.read("key1").text();
});
```

```java
// This crashes. (because it advances the read position illegally?)
tailer.readDocument(wire -> {
    wire.read("key1").text();
    wire.read("key2").text();
});
```

I was hoping I can do something like `wire.readKey()` and get the WireKey of a document, then proceed to read the document and handle it dynamically. How can I do this?

Note: I'm aware this can be accomplished using `methodReader` and `methodWriter`, and it seems like documentation/demo recommends this approach (?) But I'd prefer not to use that API, and be explicit about reading and writing messages. I assume there has to be a way to accomplish this use case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, e.g. MethodReader accomplishes it.

You can do it two ways

```
// a reused StringBuilder
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
wire.read(sb); // populate the StringBuilder
```

or a more convenient method is

```
String name = wire.readEvent(String.class);
switch(name) {
    case "key1":
        String text1 = wire.getValueIn().text();
        // do something with text1
        break;

    case "key2":
        String text2 = wire.getValueIn().text();
        // do something with text1
        break;

    default:
        // log unexpected key
}
```

For other readers who don't know about MethodReader, the same messages can be accomplished with

```
interface MyEvents {
    void key1(String text1);
    void key2(String text2);
}

MyEvents me = wire.methodWriter(MyEvents.class);
me.key1("text1");
me.key2("text2");

MyEvents me2 = new MyEvents() {
    public void key1(String text1) {
        // handle text1
    }
    public void key2(String text2) {
        // handle text2
    }
};

Reader reader = wire.methodReader(me2;
do {
} while(reader.readeOne());
```

NOTE: The content is the same, so you can mix and match the two options

You can use a Chronicle Queue instead of a Wire to persist this information

Comment: What is the difference between `wire.read().text()` and `wire.getValueIn().text()`? javadoc seems to discourage `getValueIn()` as it is marked for "internal use"

Comment: read() expected an event key, though it doesn't care which one it is.

Comment: @ccnlui I added that comment almost exactly 7 years ago :P Perhaps "advanced use" is a better description.

Comment: @ccnlui See this change https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire/commit/cbe032e4c8d0656d94972bba4a459f9ade9c49bd

Comment: Thanks, Peter, for this answer. Small question: Shouldn't the line
`Reader reader = wire.methodReader(MyEevents.class);` be
`Reader reader = wire.methodReader(me2);`?